# clear localstorage session if entered value is not equal to the value from localstorage

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have a field where the user is needed to enter a value in the input field. I want to check immediately the value is equal to the value in the localstorage name is compared with let it clear all the values in the localstorage. this snippet is not working as expected as the alert is not firing

```
$("#Id").on("input", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("Id", $(this).val());

    var name = localStorage.getItem("Id");

    if(document.getElementById('Id').value != name ){

    //clear localstorage if value not equals to localstorage value
    localStorage.clear();
    alert('localstorage cleared'); //not showing 

}
});
```

how do I clear localstorage if the value in the input field is thesame with that of the localstorage. kindly assist

Comment: if(document.getElementById('Id').value != name ){ should be a  if(document.getElementById('Id').value == name ){... your equal comparison is wrong

Comment: @KarthikGanesan i want it the entered name is not equal to the name in localstorage